# Yii2 Composer Library not loading in Component

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, yii2

I'm using the Google PHP Library that I've installed via Composer.

> "google/apiclient": "*"

I can run the test code in the view but when I try to run it in the Controller I get an error.

> Class 'backend\controllers\Google_Client' not found

Here is the Test code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("***********************");
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);
```

Comment: Are you sure didn't forget `use path\to\Google_Client;` in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
Class 'backend\controllers\Google_Client' not found
```

It seems like you didn't define namespace using.

```
use Google\Google_Client; //or somethong like this
```

If Google_Client hasn't namespace use `require` to import class from file

```
require \Yii::getAlias('common/components/simple_html_dom') . '.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Google_Client don't use namespaces. So use "\".

$client = new **\**Google_Client();